# Numpy select matrix specified by a matrix of indices, from multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array `a` of size `5x5x4x5x5`. I have another matrix `b` of size `5x5`. I want to get `a[i,j,b[i,j]]` for `i` from 0 to 4 and for `j` from 0 to 4. This will give me a `5x5x1x5x5` matrix. Is there any way to do this without just using 2 `for` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think of the matrix `a` as 100 `(= 5 x 5 x 4)` matrices of size `(5, 5)`. So, if you could get a liner index for each triplet - `(i, j, b[i, j])` - you are done. That's where `np.ravel_multi_index` comes in. Following is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

# create some matrices
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5, 4, 5, 5))
b = np.random(0, 4, (5, 5))

# creating all possible triplets - (ind1, ind2, ind3)
inds = list(itertools.product(range(5), range(5)))
(ind1, ind2), ind3 = zip(*inds), b.flatten()

allInds = np.array([ind1, ind2, ind3])
linearInds = np.ravel_multi_index(allInds, (5,5,4))

# reshaping the input array
a_reshaped = np.reshape(a, (100, 5, 5))

# selecting the appropriate indices
res1 = a_reshaped[linearInds, :, :]

# reshaping back into desired shape
res1 = np.reshape(res1, (5, 5, 1, 5, 5))

# verifying with the brute force method
res2 = np.empty((5, 5, 1, 5, 5))
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        res2[i, j, 0] = a[i, j, b[i, j], :, :]

print np.all(res1 == res2)  # should print True
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) exactly for this purpose -

```
np.take_along_axis(a,b[:,:,None,None,None],axis=2)
```